# How to fetch and show specific results from room database based on users choice(android studio)

Tags: android, search, fetch, android-room

I am making an app where the user can schedule their events and mark their tasks. In the homepage, they can open the calendar and select a date, then they can choose whether they want to mark a task, an event or see the tasks and event of the selected date. The problem is that I don't know how to search the database and show only the tasks and events of the selected date. I am new to android studio and your explanation would be very helpful in understanding how to solve this.
I am using Room database and Android studio (Java).
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wFO.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6I3a.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have accepted the answer given by MikeT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Room you would have an @Query with an appropriate SELECT statement.

e.g. say the table is named **task** (and therefore a class called **task** that has an @Entity annotation) and that a column **taskDate** is used for the task's date :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE taskDate = :taskDate")
fun getTasksOnADate(taskDate: String): List<task>
```

Calling the function would be along the lines of :-

```
val myTaskOnADate = yourDao.getTasksOnADate(the_selected_date)
```

- of course the_selected_date is set accordingly and passed by the date selection.
- by **`set accordingly`** that means in the same format as how the date is stored. So if the date is stored as YYYY-MM-DD then the value passed should be in the same format.

`myTaskIOnADate` will be a List which you can then process accordingly.